Magento2 For a logged-in customer, when I click 'View and Edit Cart,' the customer is automatically logged out after reaching the cart page
Website: www.artlounge.in
I'm encountering an issue where, after a customer logs in and adds a product to the cart, clicking on 'View and Edit Cart' causes an automatic logout. This issue occurs when there are 2 or 3 products in the cart, not just one.
I've checked the cacheable=false settings and cookies in the backend, and everything seems fine. There's nothing in the error logs, and despite trying every blog and solution I could find, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Heading

Hey, Can you once try to disable the third party module and check. Thank You!

you should be identifying these causes:
-> this issue might be causing due to enabled pwa modules in your config, whenever you tried to go to  cart it serves from pwa and didn't find any session so it gets you to login page.
->this issue might be causing due to some third party module.

You simply need to review the content of the plugin or observer. If there are any third-party observers or plugins with conditions for logging out a customer if they have more than 2 or 3 products in their cart, you should examine your extension for this and eliminate it.
It will work for you.
